# Node-Webkit: fs.readdirSync("~") does not work

Tags: node.js, filesystems, node-webkit

From the documentation for `fs.readdirSync(path)`: Synchronous readdir(3). Returns an array of filenames excluding `'.'` and `'..'`.

I do:

```
console.log(require('fs').readdirSync('~'))
```

And I get `Uncaught Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '~'`.

Am I doing something wrong or does `readdirSync` not work with Node-Webkit for whatever reason? Should I use some other way to read the home directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tilde `~` is a bash function, so Node doesn't recognize its meaning.

In this case, you will need to use the absolute path of your home directory in the `readDirSync()` function.

On Unix systems, you can also use the environment variable $HOME, of which ~ is an alias.

```
var path = process.env.HOME;
```

The Windows equivalent environment variable is HOMEPATH.

Edit :

**As OP mentioned, the npm pakage path-extra provides a homedir() method which is cross-platforms**

Comment: Is `$HOME` platform-agnostic?

Comment: It's used throughout unix systems. Of course, windows has a different name for it, it'd be HOMEPATH ;)

Comment: I see. For anyone who stumbles upon this question in the future, I ended up using the path-extra module from NPM. Just replace the tilde with `require('path-extra').homedir()` and it should work.

Comment: That's an unnecessary require in my opinion, writing it even uses more characters than process.env.HOME ;-) Any particular reason?

Comment: Then I'll need to add an if-statement to make it work with HOME in Unix and HOMEPATH in Windows.

Comment: you're right, I added the reference to my answer. Thanks!